# Magento retrieve children from specific category

Tags: php, magento

I have a problem with closing my li's and ul's at the correct moment.

With the code we have we retrieve all childeren of a specific categorie in the magento shop.

Now the problem is that i want to divide all children in lists. So we can have them sorted by category -> sub-category -> sub-sub category. I want my structure to be;

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Head Child</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Sub child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Sub sub child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Sub sub child</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Head Child</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Sub child</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Sub sub child</a></li>
                    <li><a>Sub sub child</a></li> 
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The output im getting now is

```
<ul>
    <a title="View the products for the " href="#">Head child</a>
    <li class="sub_cat">
        <a title="View the products for the " href="#">Sub child</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub_cat">
        <a title="View the products for the " href="#">Sub sub child</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is our php code;

```
<?php
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(9);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
    if($_category->getIsActive()) {
        echo '<ul><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
        $sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
        $sub_subcats = $sub_cat->getChildren();
        foreach(explode(',',$sub_subcats) as $sub_subCatid)
        {
            $_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
            if($_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_category->getName().'</a>';
                $sub_sub_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_subCatid);
                $sub_sub_subcats = $sub_sub_cat->getChildren();

                foreach(explode(',',$sub_sub_subcats) as $sub_sub_subCatid)
                {
                    $_sub_sub_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($sub_sub_subCatid);
                    if($_sub_sub_category->getIsActive()) {
                        echo '<li class="sub_cat"><a href="'.$_sub_sub_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'" category">'.$_sub_sub_category->getName().'</a>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What exactely is your question?

Comment: Please see the edited post with the output i am getting now.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using recursive function here

```
$cat =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(9);
$html = '';
$html = getSubCategoriesHTML($cat, $html);



function getSubCategoriesHTML($cat, $html) {

    $html .= '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$cat->getName().'" category">'.$cat->getName().'</a>';
    $html .= '<ul>';

    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();
    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid) {
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
        if($_category->getIsActive()) {
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html .=  getSubCategoriesHTML($_category, $html);
            $html .= '</li>;
        }
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

You can add this function in a helper or in your category model.
I haven't tested it at all so it may not work correctly. But I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am unfortunately getting an error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in on line 8